# Create event with a venue with Graph API

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to set the venue when creating a location using Graph API? So that it's actually linked to the Facebook Place.

The goal is to show the map, but I'm fairly certain that for some reason requires a Place.

```
{
"name": "Dans till Zlips",
"start_time": "2011-09-11T00:00:00",
"end_time": "2011-09-11T03:00:00",
"location": "Yesterday",
"street": "Skyttevägen 4",
"city": "Vallentuna",
"country": "Sweden"
}
```

I think this should show a place. It does not. Setting longitude, latitude or venue id (suppose that's the id of the Place) does not work.

Right now I have to manually change the location in the event edit menu if I want to have it linked, which isn't really fun or feasible when you have a couple of hundred events.

Comment: It's not documented (which I'll fix soon) but when adding the event use 'location_id' parameter and set it to the place ID

Comment: Excellent. Just tried it out and it works just fine. Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Igy Fix still isn't documented. Actually, currently it's very big headache to add proper venue with FB API...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a (currently undocumented) parameter which will mark a created event as taking place at a particular Place - When creating the event add the `location_id` parameter and set it to the ID of the Facebook Place you want

Comment: In addition to Igy's answer, there's one more undocumented feature: you can pass `city_id`.

To retrieve city_id you can make the following FQL:
    https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adcity&q=London
You'll get smth like: {
      "data": [
        {"name": "London, United Kingdom", "key": 812057, 
          "subtext": "England, United Kingdom"}, ...}
The key refers to the city_id, which could be passed to the event.create. But, these only allows to edit the map, not to show it on the created event.